# Return array as interface

Tags: go, types, interface, slice

### Case 1

I have the following method which works perfectly fine. Here I am returning an array as an interface.

```
func ReturnArrayAsInterface1() interface{} {
    retval := make([]int, 0)
    retval = append(retval, 4, 6, 8, 10)
    return retval
}
```

### Case 2

Consider the following method. Here I want to return the error in case of a panic, so I define the `retval` at the beginning and change its value in `defer`. But this shows an error "Cannot use 'retval' (type interface{}) as type []Type"

```
func ReturnArrayAsInterface2() (retval interface{}) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            retval = r
        }
    }()
    retval = make([]int, 0)
    retval = append(retval, 4, 6, 8, 10) .  // error here : Cannot use 'retval' (type interface{}) as type []Type
    return retval
}
```

So what I would like to know is, why is it that the first function works fine whereas the second does not? Are there any ways to overcome this?

### Case 3

This also works similarly to **Case 2**:

```
func ReturnArrayAsInterface3() interface{} {
    var retval interface{}
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            retval = r
        }
    }()
    retval = make([]int, 0)
    retval = append(retval, 4, 6, 8, 10) .  // error here : Cannot use 'retval' (type interface{}) as type []Type
    return retval
}
```

Comment: The second and third cases are extremely unidiomatic Go. If a function might return a value or an error, it should have two return values, like every other such function in Go - e.g. `func ReturnArrayAsInterface() (interface{},error)`.

Comment: `return []int{4, 6, 8, 10}`

Comment: Hahaha, @dolmen. It was just an example I gave. The actual values are not as simple as []int{4, 6, 8, 10} :)
Also my question is not to return that array, but to understand the working of the code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Go is a statically typed language. Your first example works because type of `retval` is `[]int`, and so you can append `int` values to it. You used [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), so the type of `retval` is inferred from the right-hand side expression, which clearly is of type `[]int`. When you return this `[]int` value, it will be automatically wrapped in an `interface{}` value.

In your second case you use a named result type, where you explicitly specify its type to be `interface{}`, and you can't append values to a value of type `interface{}` (a non-slice type). It doesn't matter that the dynamic type of the value stored in the `retval` interface value is a slice, its static type is `interface{}`.

It would work with a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
retval = append(retval.([]int), 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

But the first solution is much cleaner and more efficient.

Your third case is almost like the second: you use [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) where you explicitly state you want the `retval` variable to be of type `interface{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Case 3 will not work as in Case 2 in case of panic: in case of `panic` the `return retval` will not run, so `nil` will be returned by `ReturnArrayAsInterface3`.

To fix Case 2, use a variable with a static type as long as possible because it is safer (catches bugs) and more efficient.

```
func ReturnArrayAsInterface2() (retval interface{}) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            retval = r
        }
    }()
    r := make([]int, 0)
    retval = append(r, 4, 6, 8, 10)
    return
}
```